# ruby regex matching cent ¢

Tags: ruby, regex

I am having difficulty matching string "79¢ /lb" with this regex: (\$|¢)\d+(.\d{1,2})?

It works fine when the cent symbol appears in the beginning, but I don't know what needs to be added near the end of the string.

Basically I'm planning to extract a float value from this price tag, that is, 0.79, thanks in advance, I'm using ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that regex requires the `$` or `¢` to be at the start of the string. To match `79¢ /lb`, you'll need something like:

```
(\d+)¢
```

where the `¢` comes *after* the digits.

A single regex to match the many varied formats that you're likely to see will be a little more complex. I would suggest either doing it as multiple regexes (for simplicity), or asking another question here specifying the full range of strings you want to capture the prices from.

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo. Actually, I wanted the regex to match strings like "$3.50 kg", or "¢69 /100g", etc. I am just looking for the numeric value accompagning $ or ¢, whether they appear at the beginning or end of the numeric value, ignoring the surrounding text.

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to figure out the right regex when you consider each case separately.  If I understand your question correctly, there are 4 cases:

1. cents, with the ¢ symbol before the price
2. cents, with the ¢ symbol after the price
3. dollars (and optional cents), with the $ symbol before the price
4. dollars (and optional cents), with the $ symbol after the price

First, write a regex for each case separately:

1. `¢(\d{1,2})\b`
2. `\b(\d{1,2})¢`
3. `\$(\d+(?:\.\d{2})?)\b`
4. `\b(\d+(?:\.\d{2})?)\$`

Then, combine them into a single regex:

```
regex = %r{
  ¢(\d{1,2})\b          | # case 1
  \b(\d{1,2})¢          | # case 2
  \$(\d+(?:\.\d{2})?)\b | # case 3
  \b(\d+(?:\.\d{2})?)\$   # case 4
}x
```

Then, match to your heart's content:

```
string_with_prices.scan(regex) do |match|
  # If there was a match in the first two groups, it's for cents
  cents   = $1 || $2
  # ...and the last two groups are dollars.
  dollars = $3 || $4
  if cents
    puts "found price (cents): #{cents}"
  elsif dollars
    puts "found price (dollars): #{dollars}"
  else
    puts 'unknown match!'
  end
end
```

Note: To test this code, I had to use 'c' instead of '¢' because Ruby was telling me `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)`.  To avoid this issue, use a different character encoding, or else figure out the encoded value of the '¢' character and embed it directly in the regex, e.g. `%r{\x42}` instead of `%r{¢}`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to do everything in your reg exp;

```
#price is the string that contains the price
if price =~ /\$|¢/
   value = string.match(/\d+/)
end
```

Or something along those lines.